# CSS custom properties won't work in Ionic4+Angular Project

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am currently wokring on a Ionic4+Angular project and I am trying to make de UI. However, it seems that the custom properties for the specific UI components that Ionic has do not work.

As example, i have the following UI component:

When I try to apply the css custom properties such as the documentation provides ( ex: --background-focused-opacity) they will do nothing.

Or, if i try to do this in the scss file: --background: "color" it will not work, but if I change it to background: "color" it will work.

Any idea why this happens? I look all over the internet and I found nothing useful.

Thank you !

!Update:

What I am trying to use is the the  with the custom CSS property : --background-hover that will give me nothing

Comment: Please post complete code. There is not enough here to properly answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/serach-bar-styling-in-ionic-4-beta/137497

Some common mistakes:

**Which scss file are you using ?**

- For some components, you should always define your rules like global.scss

**Maybe you have to use the !important ?**

- Forgetting !important after your css rule will result in style not being changed.

Beacuse Ionic already has a definition on that variable, you have to override it by writing a rule that is precedes the first one.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp